# Paged List (DB + Network) triggers onItemAtEndLoaded when a DB record is updated

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-architecture-components, pagedlist

I'm building a recyclerView using Paged List library. I fetch the items from the local DataBase and when it reach the last one the `onItemAtEndLoaded()` is triggered and then it calls to the API to fetch from the network.

The items contains a favorite variable, so when the user click on it I update the item in the database and it refresh the item in the list.

The problem is that when I click in one of the last items of the list and update it in the database, the function `onItemAtEndLoaded()` is triggered and requests new items from network. So I don't want to be this triggered because there is nothing to be fetch.

Is this the normal behavior? how can I avoid it to be called?

Cheers!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find a reason and/or solution?

Comment: No. I've added and issue though https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147312106

Comment: Im having the same issue, in my case it happen I do a scroll down and I get some update on the table. But If I do a scroll down and then a little scroll up its like that method is not being called

Answer (score 1):

I now found a solution/workaround for my use case. It may be helpful to others with similar API calls, so I am posting it here.

Since `onItemAtEndLoaded()` is called whenever room touches the table (no matter if this happens via a `@Query` or `@Update` Dao function), I needed to find a way to block the logic of `onItemAtEndLoaded()` whenever meaningful.

In my case I am fetching a paged list of downloadable file URLs. When the user wants to download such a file, I update the download progress in the database. So any of these progress updates triggered the fetching of the next page from the API.

Therefore I told my Boundary Callback to at least fetch only until the last page number. I can get this information from the api response. So here is some code:

```
import retrofit2.Callback

abstract class NetworkBoundaryCallback<T> : Callback<T> {

    protected var nextPageNumber = 1
    private var maxPageNumber = Int.MAX_VALUE

    protected val ioExecutor: ExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    private val helper = PagingRequestHelper(ioExecutor)

    fun onItemAtEndLoaded() {

        helper.runIfNotRunning(PagingRequestHelper.RequestType.AFTER) {
            pagingRequestCallback = it

            // check if next page number would exceed maxPageNumber
            if (nextPageNumber > maxPageNumber) {
                // if yes, return with failure message.
                val throwable = IllegalArgumentException("Maximum page number of $maxPageNumber already fetched")
                pagingRequestCallback.recordFailure(throwable)

            } else {
                // otherwise enqueue api call for next page
                createRequestCall().enqueue(this)

            }
        }
    }

    override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, response: Response<T>) {
        ioExecutor.execute {
            val responseBody = response.body()
            if (responseBody !is PagedResponse<*>) return@execute

            // calculate maximum number of pages
            maxPageNumber = ceil(responseBody.totalItems / PAGE_SIZE).toInt()
            nextPageNumber = responseBody.page + 1
            doOnResponse(responseBody)
        }
    }
```

Using this additional variable (`maxPageNumber`) it now works fine for me.

[The PagingRequestHelper can be found here](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/PagingWithNetworkSample/app/src/main/java/androidx/paging/PagingRequestHelper.java)